# Time formatting on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am storing time as string in database. But at the view layer I want make sure that format for the time is validate.

Plus , how can add a lookup show am and pm.

At controller merge the 2 view level field into one and store in model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you store as `datetime` or `time` in your database, and use `time_select` helper method?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select

Comment: I agree with you. It's  best not to use a string but datetime or time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824158/show-time-and-week-of-the-day-in-the-view

Answer (score 1):

Datetime is gonna be the best option for you. Storing a string for this purpose has no sense.

Moreover, it's gonna be easier to format, like

article.published_at.strftime("Published at: %d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

will be something like:

Published at: 31/05/2012 11:57